# Quando usar Return e This no JAVA?

Tags: java

Estou aprendendo POO no Java e as vezes quando estou criando métodos sinto me um pouco perdido em relação ao que devo enviar para a classe principal.
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma regra básica de quando utilizar o "return" e quando o "This".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, o 'return' é quando você usa um método que não seja do tipo void, ou seja, não retorna nada. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, você usará o return para definir o que irá ser retornado quando aquela função for executada. Nesse caso irá retornar um número inteiro que é o resultado da multiplicação dos dois números da função/método.

---

Já o 'this' você usará para fazer referência ao próprio contexto em que se encontra. Resumidamente, this sempre será a própria classe ou o objeto já instanciado. Com o this você poderá fazer as modificações dos atributos daquele objeto, poderá manipular os atributos do objeto já instanciado. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Ficou claro?

Comment: Você também pode usar return em métodos do tipo void. Apenas declare `return;`. Obviamente, nenhum valor é retornado, mas dessa forma você interrompe a execução do restante do método.

Comment: Isso, esqueci de mencionar. Obrigado por ressaltar

Comment: Não use imagens de código, use a formatação disponível aqui no SOpt: selecione o trecho de código que deseja e aperte o botão `{}` aí na barra superior. Ou, se quiser atalhos de teclado, o `ctrl+k`. O mesmo efeito é obtido colocando 4 espaços antes do começo de cada linha de código

Comment: Obrigado por me avisar. Sou novo e não sabia disso.

Answer (score 2):

Herbert, boa noite!

Também estou aprendendo POO, posso estar errado mas vamos lá.
O "return" sempre é usado quando você for devolver algo a quem chamou um método.
Quando você utiliza o "this", você está apontando para uma variável.

Você pode, e vai, utilizar os dois em conjunto. Isso vai ocorrer muito quando utilizar variáveis do tipo private, onde você vai precisar de métodos públicos get e set para manipular elas.

Um método getNomeUsuario() irá ter no corpo um "return this.nomeUsuario;"